# How to add button in rows of Grid in Magento admin panel?

Tags: magento, grid, admin

I need to add button for column Status change in Grid view.

so user can change status from grid view. and I don't need to use that mass update using checkbox .

like,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried anything? Have you tried it using renderer? I don't think it would be a big deal if you have tried yourself or atleast searched online.

Check this.. http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/
It's something similar of what you want.

From next time do some research and come. Also mention in question what have you tried and failed. No one will help you in spoon-feeding.